# How do I find the treasure in devil's rock?

Tags: assassins-creed-pirates

I have found hidden treasures in all locations except the one in Devil's Rock. Animus shows 1 treasure in Devil's Rock. How do I find the one on Devil's Rock?

Comment: Is that a question at all? Or are you trying to somewhat vaguely state your achievement in the game?

Comment: @aytimothy-i only mentioned that i have found treasures in all other locations to show that i am well aquainted with the process of finding treasures(destroying ships nd going to treasure location if a treasure map was found)...but nothing like that is happening on devil's rocks i keep destroying all ships and they keep respawning without giving any treasure map. My real question was "How do I find the treasure in devil's rock?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this video will help:

The first 5 minutes are what you should watch. To find the treasure on Devil's Rock.